# Cross table comparisons, sumproduct

Tags: excel, match, criteria

I am trying to compare two different Excel (2010/xlsx) tables with related data to find matches. They would be on different sheets but in the same workbook (not that it should affect the problem).

[image: Excel Screenshot]

I think the best route is some combination of `sumproduct`, `match`, and `index`... but I haven't been able to get them to work so far. I see the main question (cell G17) being solved by creating a subset of rows from Table 2 to compare against their corresponding data in Table 1 (index/match), then using arrays to do a multiple criteria selection to count how many match the criteria I chose (`sumproduct`).

I have played around with `vlookup`, `countif(s)`, and `sumif(s)` but haven't seen a good way to apply them to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMIF as a "quasi-lookup" like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((file="doc")*(modified < SUMIF(user,creator,create)))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in a single cell as you've asked, but I would create an extra column in the second table which uses vlookup to find the created date, and another column containing whether or not the created date is greater than the modified date.  Finally, you could use countif to combine them.

To be more concrete, in your example, I would put `=vlookup(F3,A$3:D$5,2,FALSE)` in cell I3, and `=I3>H3` into cell J3, and expand both of these down.  Then cell G17 could be given by `=countif(J3:J5,TRUE)`.